How to show that $\int d^3 x\; e^{ikx}(x^1 \partial^2-x^2\partial^1)\varphi (x)=0$?
In order to show that  $J^i |\overset{\to}{p}=0\rangle =0$ when $$J^i=\epsilon^{ijk}\int d^3 x (\mathcal{J}^0)^{jk}$$ is the total angluar momentum of the field ($(\mathcal{J}^{\mu})^{\rho \sigma}=x^{\rho}T^{\mu \sigma}-x^{\sigma}T^{\mu \rho}$) in the case of  free scalar fields, I tried as follows:
My try: By the fact that $$a(k)=\int d^3 xe^{-ikx}\big[i\partial_0 \varphi (x)+\omega \varphi (x)\big]$$ where $\varphi(x)=\int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3 2\omega}\big[ a(k)e^{ikx}+a^{\dagger}(k)e^{-ikx}\big]$ is a real scalar field,  we have: $$J_3a^{\dagger}(k)|0\rangle=J_3\int d^3x e^{ikx}\big[-i\partial_0 \varphi^{\dagger} (x)+\omega \varphi^{\dagger} (x)\big]|0\rangle\\=\int d^3x e^{ikx}\big[-iJ_3\partial_0 \varphi^{\dagger} (x)+\omega J_3\varphi^{\dagger} (x)\big]|0\rangle .$$ But $\varphi^{\dagger}(x)=\varphi(x)$ (since it is real) and $J_3 |0\rangle=0$. So we have: $$J_3 a^{\dagger}(k)|0\rangle=\int d^3x e^{ikx}\Big[-i[J_3,\partial_0 \varphi (x)]+\omega [J_3,\varphi (x)]\Big]|0\rangle .$$ On the other hand, $[\varphi (x),M^{\mu\nu}]=-i(x^{\mu}\partial^{\nu}-x^{\nu}\partial^{\mu})\varphi(x)$ and $$[\partial^{\rho}\varphi (x),M^{\mu\nu}]=-i(x^{\mu}\partial^{\nu}-x^{\nu}\partial^{\mu})\partial^{\rho}\varphi(x)+(S^{\mu\nu}_V)^{\rho}_{\tau}\partial^{\tau}\varphi(x)$$ where $(S^{\mu\nu}_V)^{\rho}_{\tau}=-i(g^{\mu \rho}\delta^{\nu}_{\tau}-g^{\nu\rho}\delta^{\mu}_{\tau})$. Hence, $$[J_3,\varphi (x)]=[M^{12},\varphi (x)]=i(x^1\partial^2 -x^2 \partial^1)\varphi (x)$$ and $$[J_3 ,\partial^0 \varphi(x)]=[M^{12},\partial^0 \varphi(x)]=i(x^1\partial^2 -x^2 \partial^1)\varphi (x)+i(g^{10}\delta^{2}_{\tau}-g^{20}\delta^{1}_{\tau})\partial^{0}\varphi(x)\\=i(x^1\partial^2 -x^2 \partial^1)\varphi (x)$$ since $g^{10}=g^{20}=0$. Thus, $$J_3 a^{\dagger}(k)|0\rangle=i(-i+\omega)\int d^3 x\; e^{ikx}(x^1 \partial^2-x^2\partial^1)\varphi (x)|0\rangle .$$ Now my question is that how can we show that the latter is zero?

The integral doesn't always identically vanish.  Strictly speaking it only vanishes if you approach spatial infinity using a cylindrical geometry.
I will do the problem in 2D because the third dimension is irrelevant here.  Using polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$, the derivative $(x_1\partial_2 - x_2 \partial_1) = \partial_\theta$.  We rewrite the integral as
$$
\int_{0}^{R} dr \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} d\theta \, r \, e^{i k r \cos\theta} \partial_{\theta} \phi
$$
The integrand is obviously periodic in $\theta$.  You may expand both $e^{ikr \cos\theta}$ and $\phi$ into Fourier series of $e^{i n \theta}$.  What's more, $\partial_\theta \phi$ does not have a $n=0$ piece.  So the angular integral over $2\pi$ always vanishes.  Now you can send the cutoff $R \rightarrow \infty$ to cover the entire $\mathbb{R}^2$.
If you approach spatial infinity using the square geometry of Cartesian coordinates, strictly speaking there will be no cancellation.  However, assuming $\phi$ and its derivative vanishes fast enough at large distance, you can draw an inscribed circle inside the square, and argue that the integral over the circular disc is exactly zero, while the leftover corners also vanish at large distance thanks to $\phi$.
